# Expanding video/photos preview

Tags: grid, video, preview

I'm working on different options to preview video and photos that are laid out on a grid without triggering a pop up or a new page.

One option is the expanding preview.
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

Does anyone have any studies on usability on this method? 
What are your thoughts about using this solution for video as well as for photos?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of any usability studies for this but I've seen a lot of places use this feature...like Google Shopping: http://goo.gl/NMSshK  I personally like it.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses this very well in their image search as well. It is fairly new, but it has stuck, and I like it as well. 
Here are the drawbacks to this method:

1. After expanding, I still see a preview. This leaves me one more click to view the full image
2. When I leave this page, it takes me a while to get back to this expanded view (i.e., I don't return exactly to this spot right away, and before the page can react to my return, I've gone on to my next action.)
3. With its heavy animation and layout, it is built for desktop use but not well suited to mobile. A different solution must be accounted for regarding small screen widths.

Here is what makes Google's more usable than the example you link to:

1. "View full image" button
2. The expanded selected image preview persists after leaving the page
3. Page opens in new window.

If you can achieve a UI as usable as Google Image search, I'd say you've got a winner.